# substring match in a string

Tags: xml, substring, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSL, I have a main string in a variable and substring in another variable.

I have referred contains function to achieve this one but will not help me. :(

ex:

```
     <xsl:variable name="mainstring" select="ZXVFABEMABCD"/>
     <xsl:variable name="substring" select="ABCD" />
          <xsl:if test="contains($mainstring,$stubstring)">
                do some operation
```

The above condition is always becoming true even sub string like "ZBCD"
because contains() function returns true for alphabets presence irrespective of the order of it.

Please to help me to find the substring completely present to check the condition.

Always becomes true just if the characters present.

Comment: If you think that `contains('ZXVFABEMABCD', 'ZBCD')` returns true, you are very much mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put the strings in quotes. Because like above, the "strings" are treated as QNames (element names) and return empty (unless they are present in the XML by accident) which is interpreted as an empty string. And if the second argument is an empty string, `contains` returns TRUE.

Adding the quotes fixes the problem and `contains(...)` will work as expected:

```
<xsl:variable name="mainstring" select="'ZXVFABEMABCD'"/>
<xsl:variable name="substring" select="'ABCD'" />
<xsl:if test="contains($mainstring,$substring)">
        do some operation
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: No this is not solution ,it is always becoming true because the characters present irrespective of position in it presents the contains(...) will always become true.  i need a function which only when the respective whole string is present with order. (like strstr() in "C - Language ")

Comment: According to [fn:contains($arg1 as xs:string?, $arg2 as xs:string?) as xs:boolean](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-contains), it "Returns true if the string $arg1 contains $arg2 as a substring[...]"

Comment: It works like `strstr()`, but returns a boolean instead of a `char*`.

Comment: @SatishKumarR: I don't see your remaining problem.  Zx485 is correct.